# the value of the object is not set

Tags: xml, groovy

I've got a class `WorldGodsVoice`

```
class WorldGodsVoice extends Thread implements IThreadable {
    def innerId
    boolean isSequenced
    long wait
    def messages = []
    volatile isEternal = true
    def seq_id = 0
    ....
}
```

I `WorldGodsVoice`  wrap with another class

```
class GodsVoiceSubsystem extends Subsystem {

    def component = new WorldGodsVoice()

    def activate() {
        component.start()
    }

    def disable() {
        component.stopThread()
    }

    String toString() {
        component
    }
}
```

And keep that wrapped class inside some global object `LifeFramework`

```
@Component
class LifeFramework extends ComplexFramework {
    static final service_config = "config/service-config.xml";
    def file
    {
        file = Gdx.files.internal(service_config).file
        loaders <<      [ "godsVoice" : new WorldGodsVoiceConfigLoader() ]
        subsystems <<   [ "godsVoice" :  new GodsVoiceSubsystem() ]
    }

    def initSubsystems() {
        loaders.each { k, v -> v.load(file, subsystems[k]) }

        subsystems.each { k, v ->
            v.activate()
        }
    }

    def destroySubsystems() {
        subsystems.each { k, v ->
            v.disable()
        }
    }

    def accessSubsystem(id) {
        subsystems[id]
    }
}
```

`ComplexFramework` is just an abstract class with methods and `loaders, subsystems` fields.

Configuration for `WorldGodsVoice` I keep in the `xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<services>
    <service id="godsVoice">
        <innerId>GOD_S_VOICE</innerId>
        <wait>1000</wait>
        <messages sequenced="false">
            The world is living...Without a hero!
            The world is filled with life!
            The world is eternal!
         </messages>
    </service>
</services>
```

I process `xml` like this

```
abstract class XmlConfigSubsystemLoader {

    def load(file, subsystem) {
        def xml = new ServiceConfigLoader().load(file) // new XmlSlurper().parse(file)
        processXml(xml.'*'.find { node -> node.@id == subsystemId() }, subsystem)
    }

    abstract subsystemId()
    abstract processXml(xml, subsystem)
}
```

And abstract methods looks like this

```
class WorldGodsVoiceConfigLoader extends XmlConfigSubsystemLoader {

    def subsystemId() { "godsVoice" }

    def processXml(xml, subsystem) {
        subsystem.component.innerId = xml.innerId.text()
        subsystem.component.wait = xml.wait.text() as Long
        subsystem.component.messages = xml.messages.text().trim().split("!").collect { it.trim() } as String[]
        subsystem.component.isSequenced = xml.messages.@sequenced
        println "${ xml.messages.@sequenced }" // false
        println "${ subsystem.component.isSequenced }" // true
    }
}
```

The problem is that despite having all other fields set - it does not want to set `isSequenced` field for the object. It always returns for `isSequenced` either default or set inside object (like `boolean isSequenced = true`) value.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy truth says that any non-empty non-null string is true

You need

```
subsystem.component.isSequenced = Boolean.valueOf(xml.messages.@sequenced)
```

Comment: Hm..I wonder what prevents its for at least check for possible boolean values.

Comment: dunno, it's more aligned with Lists, maps, integers, etc this way. And to change it now would break millions of apps, so I guess this is the way it stays